# Encryption String with Session Key in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, bouncycastle, session-keys

I want to encrypt `String` with `SessionKey`. Below is sample code I am using, but I am not getting the correct encrypted answer.

```
string = test;
SessionKey = "ThisIsASecretKey";
```

For encryption, I am using the method below:

```
 byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ThisIsASecretKey");

         byte[] array1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test");
         byte[] reult = encryptUsingSessionKey(array, array1);

 public byte[] encryptUsingSessionKey(byte[] skey,byte[] data)
    {
        Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new AesEngine(), new Pkcs7Padding());

        cipher.Init(true, new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.KeyParameter(skey));

        int outputSize = cipher.GetOutputSize(data.Length);

        byte[] tempOP = new byte[outputSize];
        int processLen = cipher.ProcessBytes(data, 0, data.Length, tempOP, 0);
        int outputLen = cipher.DoFinal(tempOP, processLen);

        byte[] result = new byte[processLen + outputLen];

        tempOP.CopyTo(result, 0);
       // tempOP.CopyTo(tempOP,0,result,0,result.Length);
        return result;
    }
```

After encryption, I am getting

```
jZî|ðçê`u0aC
```

but the correct answer would be

```
ƒ_jZî|ðç_ê‹\`u0aC
```

Comment: How do you know that is "correct"?

Comment: You have better chances checking if it's correct by viewing the output in hex - that gibberish at the bottom of your question is highly dependent on whatever program you are viewing it in.

Comment: client Provided some Sample If  String is "Test" the Encrypted string would be like "ƒ_jZî|ðç_ê‹\`u0aC"

Comment: Was the sample a program you can run or have they no idea what they are doing and just sent you an email saying "It should be ƒ_jZî|ðç_ê‹`u0aC"?

Comment: First, reverse the process and see if it decrypts correctly.  Second, make sure your padding parameters are what are expected.  There are a couple recognizable character sequences that are the same in both examples.  That points to differences in padding.  Most of the characters are the same.  The customer supplied result has the extra characters `f_` at the begining and `‹\\` inserted before the last 5 characters.  Everything else is the same.

Comment: **Never** use a string as a key...  You should pass it through PBKDF2 or similar first.